# how to format character as specify length in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, format

In my database ,I have two record in a table, one's value is "201612" ,the other one is "20171" ,how to get "201701" when I query this table ? thanks

Comment: They are year and month? and you need add leading zero to month, when month defined with one character ?

Comment: @Oto Shavadze Yes,you are right. thank you for your explain about my question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
select 
    case when col > 99999 then col
        else 100 * (col / 10) + (col % 10)
    end as col
from your_table;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VONY12349)